# Traduction de « by » : « par » ou « de »

Tags: traduction, anglais, prépositions

Quand l'équivalent français de la préposition anglaise « by »  est-il « par » et quand est-il « de » ?
(Je sais que « by » peut signifier « en », « à » ou « sur » en fonction du contexte.)

Par exemple :

- Pourquoi emploie-t-on

> Frappé **par** la balle et frappé **d**'une idée

?

- Pourquoi emploie-t-on

> Ce fichier est accompagné **des** pièces justificatives.

et pas

> Ce fichier est accompagné **par** pièces justificatives.

?

- Idem

> Atteint **d**'une maladie.

et non

> Atteint **par** une maladie.

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aucune de ces tournures n'est impossible, en dehors de *par pièces justificatives* où il manque un article.

> Sans dire un mot, il ajusta le pompier, et, une seconde après, le casque, **frappé d'une balle**, tombait bruyamment dans la rue.

Victor Hugo, *Les Misérables*

> J.P. s'arrêta une seconde, comme **frappé par une idée**, sourit et reprit...

René Barjavel, *La tempête*

> *Pour ce paiement le bénéficiaire dépose également un état de frais motivé et signé, déposé en deux exemplaires, pourvu de la formule « certifié sincère et conforme pour la somme de... », **accompagné par des pièces justificatives** nécessaires à la personne de contact du projet pilote Unités de crise du SPF SPSCAE, et ceci dans les six mois après la publication du présent arrêté. ...

*Arrêté Royal du 19 mai 2010*, Belgique

> Alors qu'il est **atteint par une maladie** paralysante et souffre le martyre, Scarron écrit *Le Roman comique*, une récit burlesque plein de drôlerie.

*Bescherelle Chronologie de la littérature française: du Moyen Âge à nos jours*
Par Alain Couprie, Johan Faerber, Nancy

Comment: Wow! Quelle réponse ! Donc il n'y a pas une seule différence entre par et de  (dans ce contexte) ?

Comment: Si, certaines associations sont plus courantes, et il doit exister des cas on l'une ou l'autre des prépositions ne se rencontre pas. Je voulais simplement insister sur le fait qu'il n'y a pas de règle absolue avec les exemples proposés.

Comment: C'est une question d'_affinité_.

Answer (score 2):

En fait, **par** exprime un moyen, un acteur dans la phrase, une notion humaine, **de** sert de complément.

> Frappé par la foudre (la foudre m'a frappé) -> acteur de la phrase
>
> Condamné par le cancer (le cancer m'a condamné) -> acteur du verbe condamné
>
> Il fut haï par des racistes -> acteurs du racisme.
>
> Je suis accepté par mon beau-père. -> c'est lui qui fait l'effort de m'accepter.

On dira :

> Accompagné d'une pièce jointe // de pièces jointes. Y a pas tellement d'efforts à faire.

Enfin, il y a des subtilités, en fonction des verbes.

> Atteint d'un cancer,

est plutôt neutre, médicalement.

> Condamné par le cancer,

c'est tout à fait autre chose.

(ça veut dire il a le cancer, et les résultats ne sont pas bons, et bref, etc.,...)